# apache calcite distinguish column names from table name

Tags: java, sql, parsing, apache-calcite

I'm implementing a simple app that changes column names (and leaves table names alone) in SQL statements. The statement is passed as a `String`, and modified one is also returned as a `String`, there's no database connection involved.

To achieve this, I'm using Apache Calcite's SQL parser. I parse the SQL string to the `SqlNode`, accept a `SqlVisitor` that creates renamed `SqlNode`, and then write everything back to `String` (using `SqlNode.toSqlString()`).

The problem is that I don't know how to tell the difference between columns and tables in parsed `SqlNode` object while accepting a `SqlVisitor`. Both are represented as `SqlIdentifier`, having the same `SqlKind`. Hence, when `SqlVisitor` is visiting the `SqlIdentifier`, it will rename it whether it's a column or a table.

```
private String changeNames(String str) throws SqlParseException {
    SqlShuttle visitor = new SqlShuttle() {
        private String rename(String str) {
            return str + "-test";
        }

        @Override
        public SqlNode visit(SqlIdentifier identifier) {
            SqlIdentifier output = new SqlIdentifier(rename(identifier.getSimple()), identifier.getCollation(), identifier.getParserPosition());
            return output;
        }
    };

    SqlParser.ConfigBuilder configBuilder =  SqlParser.configBuilder();
    configBuilder.setLex(Lex.MYSQL);
    SqlParser.Config config = configBuilder.build();

    SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create(str, config);
    SqlNode parsedStatement = parser.parseQuery(str);
    SqlNode outputNode = parsedStatement.accept(visitor);

    return outputNode.toSqlString(SqlDialect.DUMMY).getSql();
}
```

for example

```
SELECT name, address, age FROM mytablename WHERE age = 23 AND name = 'John'
```

will be modified into

```
SELECT `name-test`, `address-test`, `age-test` FROM `mytablename-test` WHERE `age-test` = 23 AND `name-test` = 'John'
```

How could I tell if given `SqlIdentifier` is a column or a table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve identifiers to tables and columns, and figure out their types, you will need to use Calcite's validator (`SqlValidator`). The validator understands SQL name resolution rules (e.g. whether an aliases in a FROM clause can be seen in a sub-query) whereas we intentionally did not make the parser, and the `SqlNode` data structure it produces, aware of such things.

The two key concepts in the validator are scopes (`SqlValidatorScope`) and namespaces (`SqlValidatorNamespace`).

A *scope* is where you are standing and trying to resolve an identifier. For example, you might be in the SELECT clause of a query. Or in the WHERE clause of a particular sub-query. You will be able to see different collections of tables and columns in different scopes. Even a GROUP BY clause and ORDER BY clause have different scopes.

A *namespace* is something that looks like a table, and has a list of columns. It might be a table or, say, a sub-query in the FROM clause. If you are in a scope, you can look up a table alias, get a namespace, then look at what columns it has.

For your purposes, it would be useful if there was a variant of `SqlShuttle` that knew exactly which scope you are in, and where you could ask identifiers to be expanded into table and column references. Unfortunately no one has build such a thing yet.

Comment: what about SqlScopedShuttle ?

Comment: SqlScopedShuttle sounds like it would be useful, but it doesn't do as much as you want. It just keeps a stack of AST nodes (SqlNode) as you recurse into the tree. It doesn't know anything about SQL scoping rules.

Comment: @PiotrŚmietana if you ended up with some working code, could you share it, please?

Comment: @Arvidaa I think I've used some choppy workaround. I don't remember what exactly it was and don't have access to this code anymore, so I can't provide any details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm now using a boolean `isInFrom` in the traveling of my visitor to tell me if this node is in clause `from [xxxx]`.

Here is a simplified sample of my Visitor implementation.

```
class Visitor extends SqlBasicVisitor<Void> {
    boolean isInFrom = false;
    
    @Override
    Void visit(SqlCall call) {
        switch (call.getKind()) {
            case SELECT:
                return visit((SqlSelect) call);
            case JOIN:
                return visit((SqlJoin) call);
            default:
                return super.visit(call);
        }
    }

    Void visit(SqlSelect select) {
        boolean isInFromBackup = isInFrom;
        for (SqlNode child : select.getOperandList()) {
            if (child == null) continue;
            isInFrom = select.getFrom() == child;
            child.accept(this);
        }
        isInFrom = isInFromBackup;
        
    }
    
    Void visit(SqlJoin join) {
        boolean isInFromBackup = isInFrom;
        for (SqlNode child : join.getOperandList()) {
            if (child == null) continue;
            if (child == join.getCondition()) {
                isInFrom = false;
            }
            child.accept(this);
            if (child == join.getCondition()) {
                isInFrom = isInFromBackup;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Void visit(SqlIdentifier id) {
        if (isInFrom) {
            // it's table name
        } else {
            // it's field name
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. `isInFrom` is not accurately named, but I haven't got a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have used `calcite` `sqlParser` a bit. some of the snippet posted below.

```
  public void convertSelect(SqlSelect root) {
    convertFrom(root.getFrom());
    convertWhere(root.getWhere());
  }

  public void convertFrom(SqlNode from) {
    if (from instanceof SqlJoin) {
      convertFromOfJoinExpression((SqlJoin)from);
    }
  }

  public String extractTableFromJoinNode(SqlNode jnn) {
    if (jnn instanceof SqlBasicCall) {
      SqlBasicCall asExp = (SqlBasicCall)jnn;
      if (asExp.getKind().equals(SqlKind.AS)) {
        extractTableFromJoinNodeAsExpression(asExp);
      }
    }
    return "SomeTableAlias";
  }
```

generally, you will get `table` in the `from` statement. and you will get `columns` in `select` statement.

and last but not least, `calcite` specialises in optimise the query by applying a whole lot of optimising rules.  Depend on what you need (transforming column/table names), `calcite` might not be the best fit.